# mosfet current mirror

Tags: mosfet

[image]

I am having a tough time finding Vds, I tried to do VDD-ID*RD-VSS. but this appears to be wrong? would someone be able to poinnt out the mistake im making ?

Comment: Not at all, I offered my solution and I am unsure as to how else to approach the problem.

Comment: But can you find Vd and Vs incident? Where Vs is the voltage at Q3 source and as you can see Vg is at 0V

Comment: Vd and Vg are no problem, but I'm a tad bit confused about Vs since it is connected to the current mirror.

Comment: But Vds = Vd - Vs and Vs = Vg - Vgs = 0V - Vgs = -Vgs.

Comment: Note that Vgs Q2 and Q3 have the same Id. That means that Vgs of Q2 and Q3 is also the same (fortunately there's no body effect to consider here). Since the gate of Q3 is at ground, its source must be at -Vgs. You already know the drain of Q3 is at Vdd - Id * Rd so you can now determine Vds or Q3.

Answer (score 1):

- Id is same in Q1, Q2 and Q3 (Current Mirror). Calculate it at Q1, using:
  $$I_D=\frac{1}{2}\mu_nC_{ox}\frac{W}{L}(V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2$$
- Apply the same equation for Id at Q3 and solve for its VGS.
- Now, find Vs of Q3 using:
  $$V_{GS} = V_G - V_S $$ where $$V_G = 0  $$
- Now, find Vd of Q3 using: $$V_D = V_{DD} - I_DR_D $$
- We have found Vd and Vs of Q3. Therefore:
  $$V_{DS} = V_D- V_S$$